# Scanner asignado por referencia

Tags: java, scanner

Estoy tratando de recoger varios números para sumarlos.
El primer número que recibo, es el número de números que se introducirán por consola, y el resto son los números a sumar separados por un espacio, de modo que scanner recibe algo así:

5\n1 2 3 4 5\n

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int i = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
int resultado=0;
for (int j=0; j<i; i++){
    resultado += scanner.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(resultado);
}
```

Se supone que en i guardo el primer número que recojo, y el resto los voy sumando a resultado, pero mi problema es que i se va actualizando cada vez que hago un scanner.nextInt(); y por tanto el bluque no se está cerrando.

Es este comportamiento normal? Cómo puedo hacer para que el valor de i no varíe, cuando continue leyendo el resto de números?
Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Realmente en tu bucle tendrías que incrementar el valor de `j` y no de `i`.

```
for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
    resultado += scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Antes, por cada iteración del bucle estabas sumándole 1 más al valor de `i`. Usando `j` como índice el valor de `i` no te variará.

Comment: Ups, vaya fallo mas tonto, muchas gracias.

Comment: @pitiklan De nada. Por favor, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha resuelto tu duda.